# SharpPrivacy Error in Decrypting File

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following issue using of SharpPrivacy in .Net:

In file `Packet.cs` line 377 the value for this line always negative that causes error:
Usually the value is `'-16776588'` that is unacceptable for next step

`lLength = (bBinaryData[iBinaryDataPos++] << 24) ^ (bBinaryData[iBinaryDataPos++] << 16) ^ (bBinaryData[iBinaryDataPos++] << 8) ^ bBinaryData[iBinaryDataPos++];`

How can I solve this issue?